# Find Directory Name and Save as Variable

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to find a directory name and save it as a variable. In this case, this directory will always start with the character "2" and be the only such directory in its parent that starts with a "2". I'm trying to do the following but missing something:

```
#!/bin/bash
existing_dir=find $PARENT_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d "2*"
rm -r $PARENT_DIR/$existing_dir
mkdir $PARENT_DIR/$((existing_dir+1))
#do stuff in new directory
```

In particular, I'm trying to grab that number that starts with the "2" (the directory name will always be only numerals), not the full path. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like your missing find's `-name` parameter: ```find "$PARENT_D" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "2*"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `basename` to fetch only file name but no full path.
Then combine it with `find` when using `-exec`.

```
-exec basename {} \;
```

`{}` is the placeholder to pass a single file name to `-exec` called command, and `\;` is to finish `-exec`.

You had wrong usage of `find`. Here shows right style.

```
find $PARENT_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '2*' -exec basename {} \;
```

The whole command is generally equivalent to

```
for f in `find $PARENT_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '2*'`;
  do basename ${f};
done
```

Sum up, you should correct it by using this.

```
existing_dir=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '2*' -exec basename {} \;`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it using bash only features:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

parent_dir='/define/some/path/here'

# Capture directories matching the 2* pattern into array
matching_dirs=("$parent_dir/2"*/)

# Regex match captures the numerical leaf directory name
# from the first mach in the matching_dirs array
[[ "${matching_dirs[0]}" =~ ([[:digit:]]+)/$ ]] || exit 1
existing_dir="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

new_dir="$((existing_dir + 1))"

# If could create new directory
if mkdir -p -- "${parent_dir:?}/${new_dir}"; then
  # Deletes old directory recursively
  # @see: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2115
  rm -r -- "${parent_dir:?}/${existing_dir}"
fi
```